# Compact set and simplex

Tags: compactness, convex-geometry, simplex, convex-hulls

Assume I have an open, nonempty Set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a compact set $K \subseteq X$. Intuitively, there must be a simplex $S$ such that $K \subseteq S \subseteq X$.  I would love to see a rigorous proof for this.

I am sure there is an open cover of $K$, such that a finite subcover contains a simplex...

Comment: Let $X$ be the open unit disk of radius 1 centered at the origin; let $K$ be the closed unit disk of radius $9/10$ centered at the origin.  It seems intuitively clear that no such simplex exists...

Comment: Hmmm, if you choose the Dimension high enough...

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I mean the Dimension of the simplex. I am sure one could squeeze some simplex in

Comment: Maybe you should state what a "simplex" is, in the context of this problem.